# Display image with buttons/text in tkinter

Tags: python, image, function, button, tkinter

I'm a beginner trying to use tkinter to create a GUI. I've adapted code from other sources for my own use.

At the moment I'm trying to display an image along with a button.

However, when running the code, only the image displays no matter where I move the button, the button isn't displayed.

Would be grateful for any help.

**Additional functionality:**
I'm looking to implement a function  so that I can move the image around using coordinates, also a function that allows me to use .jpg instead of .png.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Frame):

def __init__(self, master = None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)

    self.master = master

    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):

   self.master.title("WindowName")

   self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

   quitButton = Button(self, text = "quit", command=self.client_exit)

   quitButton.place(x=400,y=400)

   self.showImg()

def client_exit(self):
    exit() # Or another function

def showImg(self):

  self.grid(row=0)
  self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
  self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
  self.original = Image.open('wire.png')
  resized = self.original.resize((200, 200),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
  self.display = Label(self, image = self.image)
  self.display.grid(row=0)

  root = Tk()

  root.geometry("600x600")

  app = Window(root)

  root.mainloop()
```